# PSCollectionView, How to Insert Item at Index

Tags: ios

I am using pscollection view for my app. Initially I loaded 30 items. What I want to do is, when it scrolls down I want to add more items after getting data from server. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

if you are talking about PSTCollectionView, you would do it like in UICollection view

```
[collectionVIew insertItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths];
```